# How can I make gravity 'stop' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, gravity

This is sort of a confusing question, but it has been bothering me and my friend for a while.

So, we have been building a JS canvas game, there's not too much to it yet, but we were trying to make the main player stop falling after reaching the bottom of the canvas. We have tried basically everything, and here's the code so far:

```js
ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
function drawTri(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
  ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
  ctx.fill();
}
class Render_3D_Object {
  draw() {
  }
}
class PhysicsObject {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.velx = 0;
        this.vely = 0;
        this.accx = 0;
        this.accy = 0;
    this.accz = 0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    tick() {
        this.x += this.velx;
        this.y += this.vely;
        if (this.velx > 0) {
            this.velx *= 0.85;
    }
        this.accy -= 0.35;
        this.velx += this.accx;
        this.vely += this.accy;
    if (this.y >= 750) {
      if (this.vely/Math.abs(this.vely) == -1){
        this.accy *= -0.85;
        this.vely *= -0.85;
      }
    }
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, -1 * this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}

class Box extends PhysicsObject {
    constructor(color, x, y, w, h) {
        super(x, y);

        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.color = color;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, -1 * this.y, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    }
}
let physicsobjs = [];
let player = new Box("green", 0, 0, 20, 20);
physicsobjs.push(player);
physicsobjs.push(new Box("black", 20, 0, 20, 20))
let movex = 0;
let movey = 0;
let triangle1 = new Render_3D_Object();
function frame() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

    player.velx += movex;
  
  player.vely += movey;
  

    for (let obj of physicsobjs) {
    triangle1.draw();
        obj.tick();
        obj.draw();
    }
}
setInterval(frame,15);

document.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {
    if (ev.key == "w")
        movey += 0.75 // up

    if (ev.key == "s")
        movey += -0.75; // down
        
    if (ev.key == "a")
        movex += -0.75; // left 

    if (ev.key == "d")
        movex += 0.75; // right
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", (ev) => {
    if (ev.key == "w")
        movey *= 0.75; 

    if (ev.key == "s")
        movey *= 0.75; 
        
    if (ev.key == "a")
        movex *= 0.75; 

    if (ev.key == "d")
        movex *= 0.75;
});
```

The lines that concern as the most are in `tick()` that start with `if (this.y >= 750)`, and end at the end of that if statement.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to store a reference to the interval created by `setInterval(frame,15)`.  When you want to stop the loop, `clearInterval(thatVariable)`

Comment: @Taplar, sorry, can you create a more understandable answer, because, my friend and I cannot get it to work. We are both quite new to javascript, but still have some experience. Again, sorry,

Comment: `var x = setInterval(frame, 15);` and when you want it to stop, `clearInterval(x);`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Examples

Comment: @Taplar, okay, thank you very much.